# How do I randomly spawn object after the number of those objects already existing is zero?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a game in Unity. I need to spawn a sphere every time the player has eliminated the other sphere.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomGeneration : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Sphere;
    public int xPos;
    public int yPos;
    public int zPos;
    public int sphereCount;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SphereDrop());
        //sphereCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere").Length - 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        sphereCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere").Length - 1;
        print(sphereCount);
        //print(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere").Length - 1);

    }

    IEnumerator SphereDrop()
    {
        while(sphereCount == 0)
        {
            xPos = Random.Range(-4, 4);
            yPos = Random.Range(1, 3);
            zPos = Random.Range(-4, 4);
            Instantiate(Sphere, new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos), Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            sphereCount += 1;
            
        }
    }
}
```

The `sphereCount` correctly measures how many spheres are in the game, but new spheres aren't being created when `sphereCount` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first time you enter the while loop, your sphereCount is 1, so it won't enter again, and consequently will never call the instantiate again.

Anyway I won't do it like this, instead I'll have two scripts, SphereSpawner, in charge of the instatiation control, and SphereObject, in charge of SphereBehaviours.

Add an event on the OnDestroy callback of the Sphere so it will call SphereSpawner to spawn a new one.

Your spawner will look like:

```
public class SphereSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spherePrefab;

    public void InstantiateNewSphere()
    {
        float xPos = Random.Range(-4, 4);
        float yPos = Random.Range(1, 3);
        float zPos = Random.Range(-4, 4);
        GameObject newSphere = Instantiate(spherePrefab, new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos), Quaternion.identity);        
        newSphere.GetComponent<SphereObject>().spawnerReference = this;
    }
}
```

and your SphereObject like this:

```
public class SphereObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SphereSpawner spawnerReference = null;

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        spawnerReference.InstantiateNewSphere();
    }
}
```

But ideally you will have a [Pool](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/object-pooling) of spheres.

Answer (score -4):

Answer moved from body of question:

---

I managed to fix the issue by adding `StartCoroutine(SphereDrop());` inside `void Update()` and removing it where it currently is.